# Advice on Transitioning from Master's to PhD in the Same Research Group

Tags: phd, masters, supervision, academic-life

I am a master's student in theoretical physics currently in my final semester in Germany. My master's thesis is already underway, and I aim to complete it by April next year. Recently, my partner and I have discussed my future job prospects, and I am interested in the possibility of continuing my research as a PhD within my current research group.

I am relatively new to academia and would appreciate advice on how to approach the idea of pursuing a PhD within the same research group with my supervisor(who is not the professor of the group) where I am working on my master's thesis. Specifically, I'm seeking guidance on increasing my chances of securing a Ph.D. opportunity within this group. Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems obvious. Have chat with the PI and discuss both your plans and your suitability in that group. The conversation might need to include your supervisor as well and it would be good to do so if you think they support you.

These sorts of things are best done face to face if that is at all possible. But it is likely the PI that makes the decisions, probably with advice from your supervisor. This is a bit less formal than what is possible by an external applicant, but can also be more productive, since people have had a chance to see and evaluate your work. Good luck.